# Reading Column values from Excel as string return as decimal?

Tags: java, excel

I have a requirement to read Excel file particular column values.

I unable to read the cell values as they are.

My code is

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;


public class ExcelSheetColumn 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Pradeep.HALCYONTEKDC/Desktop/My Data/ExcelFiles/XLS1.xls"));
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Retail - All");
    Row row=null;
    Cell cell ;
    for (int j=0; j< sheet.getLastRowNum()+1; j++)
    {
        row = sheet.getRow(j);

        cell = row.getCell(0);
        if(cell!=null)
        {
            int type = cell.getCellType();
            if (type == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
              System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString());
            else if (type == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
            else if (type == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN)
                System.out.println( cell.getBooleanCellValue());
            else if (type == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
                System.out.println(cell.getColumnIndex() + "] = BLANK CELL");
       }
    }
}
}
```

Excel column values are

```
79
999861
999861
https://staging.adpcreditsolutions.com
/index/contract_decision
9200278
2011/01/17
79
5032944200
IL4-PCC@TEST.COM
1979/12/31
0.00
0.00
```

But the output I am getting is

```
79.0
999861.0
999861.0
https://staging.adpcreditsolutions.com
/index/contract_decision
9200278.0
17-Jan-2011
79.0
5.0329442E9
IL4-PCC@TEST.COM
31-Dec-1979
0.0
0.0
```

How to read code my above program to read the excel column values as they are? Please help me!!

```
if (type == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
            {
                String stringValue=""+cell.getNumericCellValue();
                String[] splitValue=stringValue.split(".0");
                System.out.println(splitValue[0]);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 System.out.println(cell.toString());//here is the problem
```

[**toString()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method returns a string representation of the `object`. In general, the toString method returns a string that "**textually represents**" this `object`.

Use `cell.getStringCellValue()`

instead

```
cell.toString()
```

And propor usage needed.

For numeric values you have to use

[getNumericCellValue()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html)
and put a condition there

```
if(cell!=null)
        {
            int type = cell.getCellType();
            if (type == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
              System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString());
            else if (type == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)

              String[] splits = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()).split(".");

           System.out.println(splits[0]);
            else if (type == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN)
                System.out.println( cell.getBooleanCellValue());
            else if (type == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
                System.out.println(cell.getColumnIndex() + "] = BLANK CELL");
        }
```

Comment: After splitting also you are getting  the same issue?

Comment: Nope.Please tell what is your requirment.If you don't want to split then print as it is

Answer (score 0):

You can not read String value from numeric field. it throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. try this

```
 if (currentCell.getCellType().toString().contentEquals("NUMERIC")) {
        
   value = String.valueOf(currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
   value = value.endsWith(".0") ? value.replace(".0", "") : value;
}
```